# Import not used over inherited nested class

Tags: java, eclipse

My problem is quite simple: I want to use a class named `Type` (really `org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Type` in a Swing `JDialog`.

My code is (excerpt) :

```
import org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Type;

public class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    private List<Type> myTypes;
```

Problem is this does not work as expected. Eclipse tells me that the `Type` class mentioned in the `myTypes` declaration is really `Window.Type`, and my further code that uses this variable does not compile. I see that `JDialog` extends `Dialog` extends `Window` which contains a nested `Type` enum.

What surprises me is that, for instance when I want to use the `Class` class from uml package, I just import this `Class` class and the compiler is able to understand I want to use the Class in this import and not the `Class` class it would pick without the import (java.lang one). So it bugs me this does not work here, and I am obliged to use qualified name in all my code.

What further surprises me is that, according to the doc, this `Window.Type` enum was added in java 7, which means any code similar to mine would have worked until java 6 and suddenly stopped working in java 7, so a breaking change...

I use Java 8 and Eclipse Oxygen.

Is there something I miss? A compiler option or something? Is this expected and I have to live with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the Java Language Specification defines the scoping rules for member classes [JLS §8.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5) The `Type` member enum from `Window` is in scope so the import won't be used.

This isn't something that Eclipse is allowed to change as it must obey the specification.

You can refer to the UML class using its qualified name

```
private List<org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Type> myTypes;
```

Comment: Yeah, I put the eclipse tag because it might have been a bug in the eclipse compiler, but this is definitely not an eclipse subject. Ok if it is per spec, but to me, it is a very risky and poorly thought rule, with breaking changes unexpectedly happening in code... The member enum might have been the default, but overridable with imports. Like I said, my code was valid in java 6 and the change is completely unrelated.